# How to change responding variable in whole script at once?

Tags: r, variables, traits

I have data of a big experiment with more than 10 different agricultural traits (e.g. GPC, WGC, TW, TKW...). For every trait I'm using the same principle of analysis (same R scripts). My question is, is there a simple way of how to replace responding variable in whole script at once? Except of using find/replace option.

This is a part of code that I'm using. GPC is a responding variable, and after I do all the analysis on GPC, I have to do the same analysis for WGC, then TW and so on.

```
mod <- lmer(GPC ~ env/rep + gen*env + (1|env:rep:row) + (1|env:rep:col), data = df)

GEmean <- cast(gen ~ env, data = df, value = "GPC", fun = mean)
```

Is there a way, for example, of labelling responding variable in the whole script as V1 and then just changing on the beginning of the script what V1 really means, which trait it is?

Any suggestion (except of using find/replace option :D) is very welcome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may define the variable as character, then define a RHS and use `paste` with `as.formula`,

```
V1 <- "Y1"

rhs <- "~ X1/X2 + X2*X1 + (1|X1:X2:X3) + (1|X1:X2:X4)"

mod <- lme4::lmer(as.formula(paste(V1, rhs)), data=df)
```

and `cast` as usual.

```
reshape::cast(X3 ~ X2, data=df, value=V1, fun=mean)
# X3          2           3           4           5           6           7          8
# 1  1        NaN         NaN  1.25829503         NaN         NaN  0.24229907        NaN
# 2  2        NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN -1.66993472         NaN        NaN
# 3  3 0.69914031  0.52025487 -0.13089285 -0.45742957  0.68799299 -0.65833219 -0.8931447
# 4  4 0.07498591 -0.06759845 -0.15950271  0.47577484 -0.31345072  0.98613984        NaN
# 5  5 0.34686080  0.84569994  0.22288982 -0.09291759  0.07317659  0.48756834  1.0484134
# 6  6        NaN -0.47471895 -0.01001069  0.03145422 -0.35163411 -0.43344249        NaN
# 7  7        NaN  0.17256757  0.68457304  0.11125033 -0.30236288  0.06483394        NaN
# 8  8        NaN -0.12143693  0.11786080 -0.10686611  0.78027538  0.70950092        NaN
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(3L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
7L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 
7L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 3L), X2 = c(3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 
7L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
5L), X3 = c(3L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 
5L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 5L), X4 = c(3L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 6L), X5 = c(6L, 
7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 6L), X6 = c(4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
4L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L), X7 = c(4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 
5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 
2L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 3L), 
    Y1 = c(1.51381660212862, 0.504478762772218, -2.65378574088482, 
    1.43068637272239, -1.47684324896984, 1.58472803945312, -0.0922193857071082, 
    -0.823622560562235, -1.64806412194411, 0.944309458265371, 
    -0.356936363717069, -0.162015258645447, 0.12477819226619, 
    -0.288471307345202, -1.18190619708113, -2.39292785982372, 
    0.851281094397896, 0.941804900216781, -0.285843452847721, 
    -0.637399290834473, 1.01562437034261, -0.762266388284812, 
    0.57482379687021, -1.35903991270023, 0.901967856080433, 0.29778523652812, 
    -0.00277763319220751, -0.231661006943, 1.17555880002615, 
    1.1776067492362, 1.2999024919628, 2.39038283158516, -0.650154555398476, 
    -0.953405711072244, 2.07296020843138, 0.186067377477045, 
    1.27493204613466, 0.233083651874369, -1.35590587652704, 1.08696059670825, 
    0.597820644193322, -1.19390157791241, -0.452467982110459, 
    -0.325648996612789, 0.0285958447740426, -0.550033308585066, 
    -0.541233659925362, 0.213664554548748, 0.0896115607405887, 
    -2.22657886242746, -0.835933260512375, -0.3410168395334, 
    0.50787381134198, 0.531258570313673, -0.40901169495662, -0.810128911311157, 
    -0.432058431678758, -0.10219858745039, -0.254360597321428, 
    -0.154028509912877, -0.154412368645572, -2.30203996365628, 
    1.46595811311111, -1.28869300561031, -1.21053214855949, -0.268363291058948, 
    0.683392481853822, -0.319669130901838, 0.645175024187205, 
    -0.411699887457752, -0.191809472206714, -0.862892281569729, 
    -0.496653266818923, -1.82777471788403, -0.316512824335762, 
    -1.92056252600781, 0.162658786066582, 2.80586044363066, -1.90191012546795, 
    -1.37325883300246, -0.293687705724852, -0.891121986533703, 
    0.236105127173931, 1.7496394242358, 1.30113476661601, -0.681215096624127, 
    1.19455442244611, 0.850906768469736, 0.555565335896252, -0.883430008481552, 
    0.824345772604795, 0.687913712610013, 1.33576821950678, -0.808845875084407, 
    -0.0994675295096023, -0.797674770999511, -1.7176681053504, 
    -0.312094291087325, 0.480884995744134, 0.3981995835995), 
    Y2 = c(-1.53285914020452, 1.29122978508191, 0.921606245351757, 
    -0.724085415151949, 0.573933753842347, -1.75990865905637, 
    -0.913661932893341, 0.843278144910845, -0.427945566890583, 
    -0.785931108082936, 0.18126807207226, -0.98233866170379, 
    -1.69942556383645, 0.161515532679225, -0.205045971136367, 
    -0.197708729131696, 0.761530789270692, -0.361650445168573, 
    -0.284077129912569, -1.4375454413273, -1.87641468387563, 
    -0.466142684630522, -1.32675782016916, 0.0766439433592152, 
    -0.345061291806643, 1.20492953816262, -0.498983588300403, 
    -0.39017069355203, -0.585536568506376, -0.268542109333508, 
    -0.304956745639016, 0.6672974421784, -1.33856731439226, 0.260863470997641, 
    -0.229908534712624, 1.87494902300616, -1.58721820502111, 
    -1.27757830338367, -0.164744698727624, 0.822502689857642, 
    0.487841959844427, -0.644277240904474, 0.0252163852645532, 
    -1.98028441396859, 0.303527219762318, 1.27316308828519, 0.0240727927001065, 
    -0.42804136638075, -1.20095767996442, -0.632935247840562, 
    1.3552165382172, -0.343889633450751, -0.62589000162234, 1.36744315735339, 
    -1.79969327521372, -0.31448607863348, 0.0738981401409877, 
    -0.699306260552063, -0.699259392290336, 0.312939740584129, 
    0.61517017083612, 0.159816208307784, -0.0454478235356775, 
    -0.84835290813545, 0.60453967324254, -0.933994665859771, 
    -0.122862888262648, 0.499170848210818, -1.04662060255234, 
    0.24416562707757, -0.239847908251422, 0.892507692301903, 
    1.52229141743761, -1.34797780685531, 0.720419062498517, 0.0347853939462854, 
    0.0636886378960745, 1.09832215170708, 0.526957518899046, 
    -0.0574283783582475, -0.293913833682497, -0.308886513025504, 
    -0.0843275557037345, -0.761732958784744, 1.20579213927605, 
    0.53737587291791, 0.669172456819161, 0.1720175113333, 0.207695456368839, 
    0.129107054181012, 1.22029130711617, -0.388441420234782, 
    -1.08556449077231, 0.612473701706874, 0.81564534791706, -1.32961150152966, 
    0.859407793312078, -0.412360608341253, -0.188597814992205, 
    0.605501867368945)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `lapply` on the two functions. e.g.:

```
cols <- c('GPC', 'WGC', 'TW') # or use the column numbers

mod <- lapply(df[, cols], function(x) lmer(x ~ env/rep + gen*env + (1|env:rep:row) + (1|env:rep:col), data = df))

GEmean <- lapply(df[ , cols], function(x) cast(gen ~ env, data = df, value = x, fun = mean))
```

The output should be lists of analytical results.